# Disable Onepage Checkout and Multishipping Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, onepage-checkout, multishipping

I'm using Magento CE 1.9.2

For a while I was trying to disable OnePage and multishipping.

`Shipping Settings => Options => Allow Shipping to Multiple Addresses value to 'No'`

and

```
Checkout => Checkout setting = > Enable OnePage Checkout value to 'No'
```

The problem is that if these two options are set to **No**, there is no button **`Proceed to Checkout`** display on the cart page.

All I want a multi-step checkout and not want to allow multi-shipping.

Comment: That's not possible out of the box. You can either use one page checkout, or the multishipping checkout. Or you can write your own checkout method, but that's not a piece of cake.

Comment: Ok... Thanks for your reply. Is there a simple way to get one url for each step of the onestep checkout ?

Comment: That would require (a lot of) customizations. You need to develop your own checkout extension to accomplish this week or at least rewrite the default Magento checkout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento default checkout is not a real one step checkout so I reckon you can keep this value set to true.

Magento checkout is called one step because everything is happening on the same page, but the page contains several steps, and you need to finish one step to be able to go to the next one as content of next steps are loaded dynamically based on the values of the previous step.

Answer (score 0):

Hide multi-shipping link by putting this code to `app/design/frontend/{yourTHEME}/layout/local.xml` , if haven`t this`local.xml` then create it. And put this in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <checkout_cart_index translate="label">           
    <reference name="content">          
                <remove name="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" />
    </reference>            
  </checkout_cart_index >       
</layout>
```

Clear cache, and you have done.